# jquery JsTree: copy text with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

By default, the user can only click and open the tree to see the content. Is there even a way to allow users to select and copy the text content with mouse? maybe with CSS? (in this example, the texts to copy are "Simple root node", "Root node 2" ecc... in JSON 'data' object)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tree').jstree({
    'core': {
      'data': [
        { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
        { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
        { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
        { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
      ]
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: you can't. if you try to select text, you drag and drop the element with all the text